# ogr2ogr only shows specific layer name when converting dxf file to geojson

Tags: gdal, geojson, ogr2ogr, dxf

I am learning the process of extracting only certain layers inside the dxf file and converting them into GEOJSON files using the ogr2ogr of Gdal. Let me show you an example.

```
ex) ogr2ogr -f "GEOJSON" "public/images/jsonData/plants.json" -where "Layer='plants'" public/images/Ceco.NET-Architecture-Tm-53.dxf entities
```

The command confirms that only data with the layer name dxf file internal plants are extracted and converted to geojson.

In this way, you can extract the geojson file by entering the layer name inside the dxf file, but is there a way to create multiple geojson by collecting the same layers inside the dxf file with one command?

Answer (score 2):

GeoJSON file can contain only one layer, and unlike for example the CSV driver, the GDAL GeoJSON driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html does not support using a directory with several GeoJSON files as one datasource with several layers. So that alone makes it impossible to create many GeoJSON files with one ogr2ogr command.

In addition, if ogr2ogr command is using a `-sql` or a simplified `-where` parameter then the output is always a single layer because the SQL query returns only one result set.